# SELECT multiple columns using a key / index / something else

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table with the following columns:

- first_name
- last_name
- height
- social_security_number
- phone_number

Let's say I very often fetch `first_name`, `last_name`, and `height` together when I'm fetching public data, so I want to bundle them together

Similarly, I want to bundle `social_security_number` and `phone_number` as private data.

In order to simplify my queries and not make a mistake in the future, I want to create some sort of a multi-column reference that will serve as an alias to public and private data, so:

I want to do something like this:

(made up syntax)

```sql
ALTER TABLE acc CREATE BUNDLE first_name, last_name, height AS public_acc_columns;
ALTER TABLE acc CREATE BUNDLE social_security_number, phone_number AS private_acc_columns;
```

And then use it like this

```sql
 -- returns first_name, last_name, height
SELECT public_acc_columns FROM acc;

 -- returns social_security, phone_number
SELECT private_acc_columns FROM acc;

 -- returns all columns
SELECT public_acc_columns, private_acc_columns FROM acc;
```

Comment: what is bundle!!!  you can make two view to achieve your goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise creating two SQL Views. Setup one as acc_public and one as acc_private. Although I don’t know that the private would be needed.

Then you could say:

```
Select * from acc_public
```

Or

```
Select * from acc_private
```

Without seeing all your data structure, I can’t say the syntax you would need for the view, but here is some general information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Yep, this looks like the solution that best fits the "in six months, will I understand what I did?" criteria.

Comment: Simple and maintainable. Thanks.